# Mouse position in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, events, position, mouse

```
var mousemove = function(event) {
    var xpos = event.x || event.clientX;

    console.log(xpos);
}

window.addEventListener('mousemove', mousemove);
```

I have the following code which works beautifully on Chrome and Firefox but typically on IE doesn't. IE seems to be reporting the mouse position relative to the current element it's hovered over or the focal point is being switched somewhere and it's getting confused, rather than the window which the event is bound to.

The code is used on a off-canvas navigation system i am working to calculate if the mouse is less than 5% from the left of the screen (where the navigation is situated).

**Any ideas on getting it to play nicely would be awesome.**

Comment: Check this out... http://www.jacklmoore.com/notes/mouse-position/

Comment: Awesome, i will check this out and get back to you. It seems screenX is the one i am after.

Comment: Works like a dream, thanks for this extremely useful resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Tero for the resource and helping me get this fixed, please find the revised code below.

```
var mousemove = function(event) {
    var xpos = event.screenX;

    console.log(xpos);
}

window.addEventListener('mousemove', mousemove);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to do it.
One way is using jQuery.

```
$(window).mousemove(function(event){console.log(event.clientX);});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the question is for native JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

This function returns mouse position relative to the viewport or relative to the page.

```
    var getMousePosition = function(e, relativeToViewport) {
        var x = relativeToViewport ? e.clientX : e.pageX || e.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft + document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
        var y = relativeToViewport ? e.clientY : e.pageY || e.clientY + document.body.scrollTop + document.documentElement.scrollTop;

        return {
            x: x,
            y: y
        };
    };
```

Comment: `e.clientX` is the problem causer for me in IE as it's relative to the target element which seems to be getting switched.

Comment: works fine for me in IE9+, see here (open your console) ->  http://kod.djpw.cz/nhnb- it tracks relative to viewport/page, not relative to target element. what IE version are you using

Comment: That may be true for your example but the viewport changes for me as i have an offcanvas menu which slides on from the left hand side. Thanks for your help though, i do appreciate it but have this solved, at least for now...